# Expected end of statement error when using & to concatenate variables into a file name saveas

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to place a date into a filename but keep getting an "expected end of statement" error. Here is what I have so far:

```
Sub FileName()

Dim DateFileName As Variant
Dim SaveNewName As Variant

DateFileName = Format(Date, "mm.dd.yyyy")


SaveNewName = "C:\users\matt\desktop\" & "All States #1" & DateFileName & ".xls"

End Sub
```

The file name should read All states #1 3.19.2016, but anytime I use the & symbol to concatenate the .xls I get the expected end of statement error! In fact anytime I try to use it to put three things into a variable I get that error. What am I doing wrong???

Comment: I can't replicate - the posted code compiles just fine.  You might want to try restarting Excel.

Comment: Your compiles fine. Your posted code might be different from what you're actually using in terms of using a line continuation character incorrectly or some such thing. Another thing: your code is not producing the space after #1 (and before the date) that you indicate you want. Finally, you want to think about the file extension: do you need xls, xlsx, xlsm or ...

Comment: Okay, thank you. I'll try the code at work and see if it works.

Comment: I think what I was doing incorrectly was not placing spaces between the ampersand and the next piece of the variable. I was expecting VBA to do it automatically. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

When concatenating strings in VBA, **space** is required before and after ampersand operator (string1 & string2).